# Is Unity limiting my fps on Android and what can I do about it?

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine

I'm planning to benchmark the graphical performance of the Unity engine on Android.
To do that I want my application to run without any fps-limits. The problem is that I have possible encountered such a limit when using the Unity engine.

I think that Unity is somehow limiting the framerate because I've been able to run native benchmarks on my device with well above 100fps whereas an empty Unity app can't get beyond 60fps.

I have already tried setting Application.targetFrameRate to -1 and setting the project-quality settings to "Fastest". Setting the quality settings to the fastest settings should have disabled VSync which in my experience often caused a 60fps limit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: device refresh rate is fixed to 60 fps. High framerate performance tests aren't very helpful actually, so just make your test complex enough that it won't run at 60 fps or more. You want to test high load (real world) situations more than synthetic single-item tests.

Comment: My goal is to compare these Unity-benchmarks against existing native benchmarks. Those native benchmarks achieve much more frames per seconds than the 60fps-limit. I'm completely aware that it might not be 100% useful to do synthetic single-item tests.
What I'm hoping for is some advice on how to keep unity from limiting my application to run at 60fps max.

Comment: it's not unity, mobile device refresh rates are locked at max 60 Hz

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are you sure that the 60 Hz limit is linked to Unity apps only getting 60 fps at max?
Please correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't the fps be independent from the screen refresh rate with VSync turned off?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say: mobile device refresh rates are locked to a 60 Hz refresh rate, you can not turn off VSync on mobile devices. This has nothing to do with Unity, all game engines are locked to 60 Hz on mobile.

Comment: I've actually managed to turn off VSync on my android device and achieved 100+fps on my Unity demo app.
To do that you need to edit the file /system/build.prop and add the following line "debug.egl.swapinterval=0". After rebooting VSync is disabled and your framerate is unlimited!